# FastText or GloVe for code-mixed sentiment analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, word-embeddings

I am currently working on a project for code-mixed sentiment analysis (English+Spanish). I've been using the GloVe Twitter word embeddings so far but I realized that even though this representation is multilingual, it is most likely ***not aligned between languages***, which I think impacts the quality of the sentence representation.

So I am trying out the FastText aligned word embeddings downloaded [here](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/aligned-vectors.html) and I've been computing cosine similarities of English/Spanish words within GloVe and same with the respective *aligned* files, and it shows stronger similarity in fastText for actually closer words, and stronger dissimilarity between opposite words (see code below).

What I need is an opinion on these assumptions:
- Results below are a good indicator that I should rather use fastText embeddings which will allow better representation.
- If yes, should I use fastText embeddings by concatenating Spanish-English files?
- If yes, I should deal with duplicate words by averaging their vectors in order to keep it simple.

code:

```py
>>> from fasttext import FastVector
>>> #loading embeddings
>>> e = FastVector(vector_file='./fastText/wiki.en.align.vec')
reading word vectors from ./fastText/wiki.en.align.vec
>>> s = FastVector(vector_file='./fastText/wiki.es.align.vec')
reading word vectors from ./fastText/wiki.es.align.vec
>>> g = FastVector(vector_file='./glove.twitter.27B/glove.twitter.27B.200d.txt')
reading word vectors from ./glove.twitter.27B/glove.twitter.27B.200d.txt
>>> #compute cosine similarity
>>> def f(emb1, emb2, w1, w2):
...     w_en = emb1[w1]
...     w_es = smb2[w2]
...     print(FastVector.cosine_similarity(w_en, w_es))
...
>>> f(e, s, "dog", "perro")
0.5871925259757504
>>> f(g, g, "dog", "perro")
0.36327244845041556
>>> f(e, s, "dog", "gato")
0.43565656007837456
>>> f(g, g, "dog", "gato")
0.31090089925549624
>>> f(e, s, "murder", "alegria")
-0.05121494642496044
>>> f(g, g, "murder", "alegria")
-0.011452790766085442
>>> f(e, s, "murder", "asesinato")
0.5567438582337103
>>> f(g, g, "murder", "asesinato")
0.2374400637804554
```